# How do I inspect html in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm trying to write some simple code that refreshes the page, reads from the html in the page, and follows a link or not based on text in the html.

I know how to set the page to an address, and I know what in the html I'm looking for (a particular div class), but I can't seem to find out how to actually bring the html information into the program to be inspected.

Does anyone know what command/s I should use?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: Not a fan of the site but this covers it https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Comment: Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug) for inspecting and debugging. It has really great features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for selecting any element on the page. Since you're searching for a `div` with a particular class, you can use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

I would recommend instead searching for elements by `id` with [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). The reason is because classes in HTML can be used on multiple elements and they're typically used for making sure a group of elements has the same behaviour and/or style. `id` attributes on the other hand are meant to be used only on ONE element on the page, and from your post this seems like the more appropriate use case.

After you've gained some experience with raw Javascript DOM manipulation, you can take a look at [jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, this should let me get my code up and running :)

Comment: It's 2017. Do you really think it's still a good idea to encourage people to take a look at jQuery?

Comment: jQuery does the job of DOM manipulation very well, and if a page is mostly static then adding a fancy view library to the mix might introduce an unnecessary abstraction. jQuery is simple to understand and it should serve only as a stepping stone between the DOM and a framework.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is the value of an input field, you can use the following code to get the value of that input field :

```
 document.getElementById('idOfYourHTMLElement').value
```

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68sqkf6z/) for a demo.

If your text is between a `<span>` and a `</span>` (or any open + close tag pair), you can use the following code to get the value of that text :

```
document.getElementById('idOfYourHTMLElement').innerHTML
```

See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68sqkf6z/) for a demo.

You can use eg. `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementsByClassName` for fetching the element(s) you need, but it's both easier and better for performance to always use a (unique) ID if you want to do something specific with a specific element, in combination with `document.getElementById`.

Anyway, you might want to do some reading on [the basics of DOM manipulation in JavaScript](http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation).